# Calculate the execution time of a method

Tags: c#, .net, timer, io, stopwatch

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [How do I measure how long a function is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107140/how-to-measure-how-long-is-a-function-running)

I have an I/O time-taking method which copies data from a location to another. What's the best and most real way of calculating the execution time? `Thread`? `Timer`? `Stopwatch`? Any other solution? I want the most exact one, and briefest as much as possible.

Answer (score 1461, accepted):

[`Stopwatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-8.0) is designed for this purpose and is one of the best ways to measure time execution in .NET.

```
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
// the code that you want to measure comes here
watch.Stop();
var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

[**Do not** use DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637/is-datetime-now-the-best-way-to-measure-a-functions-performance) to measure time execution in .NET.

---

UPDATE:

As pointed out by @series0ne in the comments section: If you want a real precise measurement of the execution of some code, you will have to use the performance counters that's built into the operating system. The [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409762/creating-a-perfmon-counter-to-record-an-average-per-call-c/1409833#1409833) contains a nice overview.

Comment: Exactly, and what about this case: i have a foreach loop that has a `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
{
    CopyFiles(folder, dest);
});
` inside, but stopwatch stops before everything is done.

Comment: Then you should put your Stopwatch inside the delegate in order to measure the performance of the CopyFiles method.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - Stopwatch isn't entirely accurate? remember that .NET background noise (such as JITing) causes varying execution times to occur. Therefore, realistically, for accurate measurements, the OP should be using a performance profiler.

Comment: @series0ne, very good point. I will update my answer to include your valuable comment.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, I recently had an interview with a very skilled senior developer. He pointed out to me that using DateTimes is actually more accurate than using a StopWatch. He said the reason for this is that the Stopwatch in .NET does not take into account CPU affinity, and therefore, if your thread moves from one core to another, the StopWatch doesn't take into account the execution time across the other cores; only the one where the thread began execution. What is your opinion on this?

Comment: @series0ne, what the senior developer told you about the Stopwatch and DateTime is absolutely true. Except that with DateTime you do not have enough accuracy. The problem is that there is no such class in .NET that would allow you all those features.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, I see. He also told me of a CPU affine StopWatch/Timer that someone had written and posted on public source sites (CodePlex/Code Project)...I've yet to find it!

Comment: It always return 1.

Answer (score 95):

From personal experience, the `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class can be used to measure the execution time of a method, however, **BEWARE**: It is not entirely accurate!

**Consider the following example:**

```
Stopwatch sw;

for(int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
{
    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    DoSomething();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

sw.Stop();
```

**Example results**

```
132ms
4ms
3ms
3ms
2ms
3ms
34ms
2ms
1ms
1ms
```

Now you're wondering; *"well why did it take 132ms the first time, and significantly less the rest of the time?"*

The answer is that `Stopwatch` does not compensate for "background noise" activity in .NET, such as JITing. Therefore the first time you run your method, .NET JIT's it first. The time it takes to do this is added to the time of the execution. Equally, other factors will also cause the execution time to vary.

What you should really be looking for absolute accuracy is **Performance Profiling**!

**Take a look at the following:**

RedGate ANTS Performance Profiler is a commercial product, but produces very accurate results. - [Boost the performance of your applications with .NET profiling](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)

Here is a StackOverflow article on profiling: - [What Are Some Good .NET Profilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers)

I have also written an article on Performance Profiling using Stopwatch that you may want to look at - [Performance profiling in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629032/performance-profiling-in-net)

Comment: Good point +1. Thanks for your accuracy, I accepted Darin's answer for the sake of simplicity, accuracy was in the second level of importance in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is an example of *inaccuracy*. The stopwatch is accurately measuring the total cost of the first call, which surely is what is relevant to the customer who is going to be running this code. They don't care whether those 132 milliseconds are charged to the method execution or to the jitter, they care about the total time elapsed.

Comment: @EricLippert you raise a good point here, admittedly if the code is only going to be run once, then yes, JITing and various other "noise" will credibly factor into the result, however the OP (and indeed others) may have other scenarios, for example, the code may be executed in a loop, therefore you might calculate the average of all iterations, or require the longest/shortest execution time.

Comment: @series0ne If you care about the performance of a loop, then measure the performance of a loop. Don't simply assume that doing something *n* times means it will be exactly *n* times slower as executing it once.

Comment: Besides that on average a PC is doing lots of things in the background, so stopwatch should not be taken too literal, but as an indication

Comment: First off, the code sample should produce the output with ever-increasing number as StopWatch is never reset in the loop. And by "should" I mean it does (I checked). So your output does not match the code. Second, when I corrected the code to do a Stop/Write/Reset/Start in the loop, the first measurement was the same as the rest. My guess is your DoSomething does something for longer the first time it runs. JIT may or may not be the reason for it, but it's not that Stopwatch is affecting the measurement. Hence -1.

Comment: @ILIABROUDNO did you notice that after 10 runs the program stops? You’ve obviously modified the code

Comment: ILIA BROUDNO is absolutely correct, I got the same results. @series0ne, you have a Console.WriteLine inside the loop, writing the ms so far; because you only stop the watch AFTER the loop ends, it is increasing over time with each iteration, so we should see something like 3, 6, 10, 12, 15... as the time accumulates over the executions.

Comment: @RuiMiguelPinheiro Yes, so I see. My latest update should put that right

Answer (score 42):

[`StopWatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class looks for your best solution.

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
DoSomeWork();
sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Time taken: {0}ms", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Also it has a static field called [`Stopwatch.IsHighResolution`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.ishighresolution.aspx). Of course, this is a hardware and operating system issue.

> Indicates whether the timer is based on a high-resolution performance
>   counter.

Answer (score 21):

If you are interested in understand performance, the best answer is to use a profiler.

Otherwise, [System.Diagnostics.StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) provides a high resolution timer.

Comment: Absolutely correct! I'm a little disheartened that so many on here have suggested using the Stopwatch, as it is not entirely accurate. However as you suggested using a Performance profiler, this is the correct way to do it! +1

Answer (score 13):

Following this [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netcore-3.1):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        stopWatch.Stop();
        // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

        // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
        Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
    }
}
```

Output:
`RunTime 00:00:09.94`

Answer (score 7):

[StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) will use the high-resolution counter

> The Stopwatch measures elapsed time by counting timer ticks in the
>   underlying timer mechanism. If the installed hardware and operating
>   system support a high-resolution performance counter, then the
>   Stopwatch class uses that counter to measure elapsed time. Otherwise,
>   the Stopwatch class uses the system timer to measure elapsed time. Use
>   the Frequency and IsHighResolution fields to determine the precision
>   and resolution of the Stopwatch timing implementation.

If you're measuring IO then your figures will likely be impacted by external events, and I would worry so much re. *exactness* (as you've indicated above). Instead I'd take a range of measurements and consider the mean and distribution of those figures.

Answer (score 7):

You also use this, "Gets the number of milliseconds elapsed since the system started."

```
System.Environment.TickCount
```

For example

```
static void method1()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test1 " + i);
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var startTime = Environment.TickCount;
    method1();
    var endTime = Environment.TickCount;
    Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + (endTime - startTime));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 using System.Diagnostics;
 class Program
 {
    static void Test1()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test1 " + i);
        }
    }
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        Test1();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time Taken-->{0}",sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, it's not a good idea to re-create `Stopwatch` class every time, what you can do instead is use its `GetTimestamp` method, like this:

```
var startTime = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();

// do some work ...

var endTime = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();

var elapsed = TimeSpan.FromTicks(endTime  - startTime);
```

This is more accurate and won't be allocated any memory.

And if you are using `.NET 7.x` and above, you can do this instead:

```
var startTime = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();

// do some work ...

var elapsed = Stopwatch.GetElapsedTime(startTime);
```

---

And here is a small wrapper to make it more fun:

```
TimeSpan Benchmark(Action action)
{
    var startTime = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();

    action.Invoke();

    return Stopwatch.GetElapsedTime(startTime);
}

// usage:
var elapsed = Benchmark(() =>
{
    // do some work ...
});
```

Comment: Caution, see the note in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedticks): *"Stopwatch ticks are different from `DateTime.Ticks`"*. For the correct way to convert from one tick unit to the other, see this: [How do you convert Stopwatch ticks to nanoseconds, milliseconds and seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329079/how-do-you-convert-stopwatch-ticks-to-nanoseconds-milliseconds-and-seconds)