# How do calculate execution actual time using stopwatch in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I tried the following code in a method:

```
Trace.Write("START "+Datetime.now);
//DATABASE METHOD CALL 
SaveData();
Trace.Write("END "+Datetime.now);
```

And I calculate the time in `output window` manually.

How do I use `stopwatch` (start/reset/stop) to get the correct execution time?

Comment: You mean you don't know how to instantiate a class and invoke its methods? Your profile says you are experienced with c#

Comment: This is an obvious case of RTFM. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019510/calculate-the-execution-time-of-a-method

Comment: Wow... for a user with fairly decent rep this is just appalling... A very simple Google search would have yielded many results for this.  And then you go and mark your own question as a duplicate.

Comment: yea i know but question not posted by me

Comment: @ashish, what do you mean "question not posted by me"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an instance of [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) by [`Stopwatch.StartNew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.startnew%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), execute your method. Stop the `Stopwatch` and then get `ElapsedMilliseconds` like:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
SaveData();
stopwatch.Stop();
Trace.Write("Time in Millisecond:  " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Remember to include `using System.Diagnostics;`

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Stopwatch](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch) class:

```
    // Create new stopwatch
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    // Begin timing
    stopwatch.Start();

    // Do something
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }

    // Stop timing
    stopwatch.Stop();

    // Write result
    Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}",
        stopwatch.Elapsed);
```

Answer (score 2):

As per msdn:

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
Thread.Sleep(10000);
stopWatch.Stop();
// Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
```

[StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)