# C# How to measure function time execution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a C# function that I want to measure execution time:

```
// save audit log using XML approach
if (records > 0) {

    using(SQLRepository repo = new SQLRepository()) {

        // this is one approach that I want to meassure
        repo.SaveChangeLog(tw.ToString());

        // this is second approach that I want to meassure
        repo.SaveChangeLogApproach2(tw.ToString());
    }
}
```

Is there something already in Visual Studio that I can use to get those executions times?

Comment: Have you come across AOP (Aspect Orientated Programming)? Might be useful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019510/calculate-the-execution-time-of-a-method

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` ?

Comment: VS2015 displays on diagnostic tools window with a breakpoint at the end of the function. see my answer on duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the [`System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you time both method calls within the same using statement, the first call may be slower due to instantiation of the repo class.