# Unchecking/Checking 500+ DataGridViewRows with CheckBoxes faster

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

I currently have an issue with checking and unchecking a lot of checkboxes in a datagridview. I already run them parallel but its still really slow, even loading the rows in is faster...

**EDIT: Issue is fixed. The `AutoSizeColumnsMode` and `AutoSizeRowsMode` caused it to slow down!**

```
if (checkBox_all.Checked)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(dataGrid_searchEntryList.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>(), row =>
    {
        row.Cells[0].Value = true;
    });
}
else
{
    Parallel.ForEach(dataGrid_searchEntryList.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>(), row =>
    {
        row.Cells[0].Value = false;
    });
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[Picture of the gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irKsm.png)

Comment: `DataGridView` is not thread-safe. You can't use `Parallel.ForEach`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45089128/how-to-change-the-cell-value-for-entire-datagridview-column may be of interest as an approach to try.

Comment: is it data bound?  if so, try to update the objects instead

Comment: @JohnG no just this one task.

Comment: @mjwills I also want to implement it so that you can check the boxes by names in the 3rd cell and invert the check. I will add a pictrue to op in a second.

Comment: I can not imagine what kind of delay you are experiencing. My test took a little under a half a second to process 6001 rows. As Zero's answer states... you can not use Parallel with the `DataGridView`

Comment: @JohnG for me it takes over 10 seconds. Could it be due to a lot of other cells in the grid view ? I have 6 collums.

Comment: I doubt if the number of columns will make a difference. In addition, it appears to take LESS time when the grid does not have a data source. Without a data source and 7 Columns, 6001 rows it took 0.0029074 seconds to change all the check boxes.

Comment: @JohnG I fixed my issue, I updated op with it!

Comment: You may also want to consider [double-buffering the dgv.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41893708/how-to-prevent-datagridview-from-flickering-when-scrolling-horizontally/41894210?s=1|53.9115#41894210)

Comment: @DeathRGH You really should try my solution.  Your fix is a work-around for excessive drawing.  You don't need to modify auto-sizing if you suspend drawing while you update.

Answer (score 0):

First off you cannot access WinForms controls outside of the GUI thread.  So you need to eliminate the `Parallel` calls.

Oddly, `DataGridView` does not have `BeginUpdate/EndUpdate`.  But you can suspend drawing:

```
dataGrid_searchEntryList.SuspendDrawing();
//Update multiple cells here
dataGrid_searchEntryList.ResumeDrawing();
```

This at least eliminates excessive drawing.

Worth noting that if this is databound there's a much better way of doing this.  But I'm presuming it's not as you're accessing data via the `DataGridView` itself.

Finally your code can be simplified to just this:

```
foreach(var row in dataGrid_searchEntryList.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>())
{
    row.Cells[0].Value = checkBox_all.Checked;
}
```

Comment: No its not databound, I will check that out and see if it helps in my situation...

Answer (score 0):

**Issue is fixed. The `AutoSizeColumnsMode` and `AutoSizeRowsMode` slowed it down!**