# Calculate the time difference between two timestamps

Tags: powershell, datetime

I want to calculate the difference between two time stamp no matter even it is second, here below is my code snippet:

```
#Start Timer
$Start_Timer = (Get-Date).DateTime
Write-Host "Start Timer is ---> $Start_Timer"
#End Timer
$End_Timer = (Get-Date).DateTime
Write-Host "End Timer is ---> $End_Timer"
$Current_Time_End = (Get-Date).DateTime
$TotalExecutionTime = $End_Timer - $Start_Timer
```

Output of the above code is:

```
Start Timer is ---> Monday, August 13, 2018 6:21:18 PM
End Timer is ---> Monday, August 13, 2018 6:22:55 PM
```

Error generated

```
Cannot convert value "Monday, August 13, 2018 6:22:55 PM" to type
"System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At D:\Eclipse_Repository\self_repo\jmallick\FileMover.ps1:55 char:1
+ $TotalExecutionTime = $End_Timer - $Start_Timer
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `$TotalExecutionTime = [datetime]$End_Timer - [datetime]$Start_Timer`

Comment: `(Get-Date).DateTime` -> `Get-Date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [StopWatch] for performance measurement. See following example:

```
$timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
#do your job
$timer.Stop()

#get timespan
$timer.Elapsed
```

Answer (score 2):

`(Get-Date).DateTime` is a string so you cannot do mathematical operations. You can verify this with `(Get-Date).DateTime.gettype().fullname`.

Using subtraction on the pure date objects e.g. `$beforeTime = Get-Date` will be what you want to do. This will also return `TimeSpan` objects

```
(get-date) - ((get-date).addhours(-1))
```

Also read this [relevant post about calculating execution time in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019510/calculate-the-execution-time-of-a-method) and [using `StopWatch` in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48153565/net-stopwatch-and-powershell)

Answer (score 2):

I use this

```
$t1 = (get-date)
$t2 = (get-date)
$tdiff = $t2-$t1
```

Output variable example:

```
$tdiff
$tdiff.minutes
$tdiff.hours
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

Use this: 
`New-TimeSpan -Start $Start_Timer -End $TotalExecutionTime`
You'll have time difference expressed in multiple increments (days, seconds etc).