# How to calculate the elapsed time of executing action in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to calculate the elapsed time any action and save it in the database.
i dont Use stopwatch in all actions.

I am looking for a way that can be applied to the entire project asp.net MVC
in other word There is an event that happens in every time executed  a action?.

Comment: Use stopwatch refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019510/calculate-the-execution-time-of-a-method

Comment: i dont Use stopwatch in all actions, I am looking for a way that can be applied to the entire project asp.net MVC

Comment: Please elaborate `entire project ASP.NET MVC`. Did you mean every action life cycle?

Comment: You need to include libraries like PostSharp to do this task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do something like this. 
1. Create Filter.

```
public class ActionExecutionTimeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Items["ActionName"] = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Items["StartTime"] = DateTime.UtcNow;
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
        // Do this to calculate only Action Execution Time
        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
            DateTime startTime = (DateTime)filterContext.HttpContext.Items["StartTime"];
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(filterContext.HttpContext.Items["ActionName"].ToString() + "-" + (DateTime.UtcNow - startTime).TotalMilliseconds);
        }
        // Do this to calcution of Action Start to Result Process
        public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
            DateTime startTime = (DateTime)filterContext.HttpContext.Items["StartTime"];
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(filterContext.HttpContext.Items["ActionName"].ToString() + "- (R)" + (DateTime.UtcNow - startTime).TotalMilliseconds);
        }
    }
```

2. Register in Global.asax

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new ActionExecutionTimeAttribute());
    }
}
```

3. You have to do How to insert data in DB.

Answer (score 1):

Use [MiniProfiler](https://miniprofiler.com/), from the makers of StackOverflow. Very easy to use, and by default gives measurements such as the execution of controller actions.