# Create a custom attribute for measuring code execution time

Tags: c#

I using C# and woundering if it possible to create a custom attribute that will measuring execution time of code.

I'll explain. Let's say that you have the class `Task`:

```
public class Task
{
    public void Run()
    {
        Do1();
        Do2();
        // ...
    }

    public void Do1()
    {
        // ...
        Thread.sleep(10); // Dummy
    }

    public void Do2()
    {
        // ...
        Thread.sleep(5); // Dummy
    }
}
```

And the main file:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Task task = new Task();
    task.Run();
}
```

Now, I running this code on my server and feel that its running too slow (then I expected). So I using my brand new attribute to measuring execution time - let's call it `MeasuringTimeAttribute`:

```
[MeasuringTime]
public void Run()
{
    // ...
}
```

When running the code again, I want it to generate a report that looks like this:

```
Run() - Took 15s
    Run().Do1() - Took 10s
    Run().Do2() - Took 5s
```

The basic idea is that it will measuring for my code even if I have more then 2 levels (like in this example). Also, no matter what code it's running on. All I have to do is to add the `[MeasuringTime]` attribute the entry-point function.

Is this possible? If yes, I will appreciate every tip I'll get in order to implement it.

Comment: Take a look at https://miniprofiler.com

Answer (score 2):

Attributes do not change the way your code is executed. You should implement this time measuring in your server code yourself, from scratch, [using `Stopwatch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019510/calculate-the-execution-time-of-a-method/14019526) or any other native or 3rd party utilities.

It will also be very difficult to handle nested calls.

In general, it looks like you are reinventing the wheel - there is a sort of software called "profiler". It will profile the execution time, memory consumption and other characteristics of your code during runtime. For example, you can use JetBrains DotTrace.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I know the class `Stopwatch` and using it. This question is part of my "learning". I know that I can use ready-to-use profiler. Just wondering if it possible to create a mini-profiler myself.

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever Yes, of course. Just add a check to your server code before and after method execution: if there is such attribute - measure time and output it somewhere. How to do this depends on your server architecture.

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever There should be some libraries around for "decorating" methods (so add some benchmarking code). https://github.com/pardeike/Harmony. Haven't ever used it... Or you could modify the compiled program with Fody to add the benchmark code.