# Searching list with OfType vs GetType == typeof

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a collection:

```
public class Cat : Animal {} 
public class Dog : Animal {}

private List<Animal> _animals = new List<Animal>(){ new Cat(), new Dog() };
```

Lets argue that there are a million "Animal" object with lots of different types of animals in the list.

Which method is quicker:

```
var animal = _animals.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Dog));
```

or

```
var animal = _animals.OfType<Dog>.FirstOrDefault();
```

Should I use OfType or GetType() == .

Comment: They don't do the same thing - if you have `public class Dachsund : Dog` then any instances of `Dachsund` *won't* be found by your `GetType` method, but *will* be found by `OfType`. Also note that both of your solutions use `FirstOrDefault`, so your final sentence is a bit unclear. In terms of performance, see https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Yes - I have made a mistake in my last sentence, i have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to sort the list and then you can check the results and compare  :

```
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
// the code that you want to measure comes here
watch.Stop();
var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

[Calculate the execution time of a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019510/calculate-the-execution-time-of-a-method/14019526)